# Explanation of "unbound placeholder parameter"

Tags: scala, function, scala-placeholder-syntax

## Question

Why case 2 causes "unbound placeholder parameter" while case 1 is OK?

### Case 1

```
val h: (Int => Int) = (x:Int) => { scala.util.Random.nextInt(x) }
val _h: (Int => Int) = { scala.util.Random.nextInt(_) }
h(5)     // 3
_h(5)    // 3
```

### Case 2

```
val f: (Int => Int) = (x:Int) => { x }
f(5)     // 5
// Causes error
val _f: (Int => Int) = { _ }   <----- unbound placeholder parameter
```

Comment: There is no way `_` can be a valid `Int => Int`, whereas `scala.util.Random.nextInt(_)` is one (aka infered as `scala.util.Random.nextInt(_: Int)` or `{ i: Int => scala.util.Random.nextInt(i) }`)

Comment: first case is lambda expression: 
`{ i: Int => scala.util.Random.nextInt(i) }`
but in case 2 you have just empty block, it don't waiting for some arguments and don't know what to return. You can't replace by placeholder any argument of function which has empty body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.nextInt(_)` is not an example of placeholder usage. In this case the underscore `_` is used for "eta expansion" of the `nextInt()` method, i.e. promoting the method to a proper function. The result is equivalent to the following:

```
val _h: (Int => Int) = util.Random.nextInt
```

To get your `_f()` code to work you could do this.

```
val _f: (Int => Int) = identity
```

Answer (score 3):

`_` is never interpreted as `x => x` in Scala.

If I understand the part of [language spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions) where it talks about "binding underscore sections" correctly, this is precisely because Scala reserves `_` for partial application. Like in case of `scala.util.Random.nextInt(_)` it means `x => nextInt(x)` and not `nextInt(x => x)`.